# Sort dictionary with multiple values based on sum

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, multiple-value

I have a dictionary like this

```
({'Apple': [1,5,3,1,6], 'Banana': [9,12,4,5,1]})
```

and I want to create a sorted list out of it where sorting is based on the sum of the values.

The following code does not work though:

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

It always says `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

If I leave out the `sum` function it works, but sorting is based on the FIRST value in the list. If I try something like `key=lambda x: (x[1][0]+x[1][1])` it sums up the first two values in the list and sorts based on the result. So sorting based on the sum DOES WORK, but not with the `sum` function but only by manually adding the elements. Why though?

Comment: Somewhere earlier in your program, you assigned `sum` to be an int, shadowing the built-in. Or at least that's my guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, your code works for me.

Comment: Thanks. I feel dumb because I didn't notice I already had the variable `sum` in my code. I renamed it and it works.